# How to create video packets in Qt for RTP payload

Tags: qt, rtsp, rtp

I am currently trying to implement an RTSP/RTP server using Qt. I would like to read from a video file into a QByteArray so that it may be split up into fragments and added as the payload of a RTP packet. Would this be the correct approach and if so what would the code be to read a media file (such as "movie.3gp") into a QByteArray? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't want to load the whole file at once, but incrementally?

Comment: What code have you tried? Share that first. Then I will tell you what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had done it in the past with Qt 3.3. Back then I used ffmpeg if I'm not mistaken to compress the stream from a camera and [live library](http://www.live555.com/) to generate the RTSP/RTP stream. Basically as you said, loading each frame into a QByteArray and moving it to live API.

Now Qt has [Phonon](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-module.html) and [QtMultimidia](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtmultimedia.html) modules that probably could read the file directly, but to use it, looks like you would have to create a video sink that implements the streamming. Should be possible, creating a phonon plugin, perhaps using live.

Unfortunally you can't acess a QVideoFrame from a Phonon source using the current API (4.8.0) as far as I can tell. So either using other libs as I did in the past or creating a new phonon plugin seems like the only 2 ways to accomplish it.

Hope this can get you in the right direction.